# View users connected to ad-hoc network

Tags: networking, adhoc

I created an ad-hoc network to share my hard-wired connection with other computers/devices, but I can't find anywhere a place that shows the connections. Can I? Where is it?

Assuming it exists, what information is available about the connected devices? Are there multiple locations to get information about them?

Answer (score 4):

One approach may get you information about the devices recently transferring data to and from  your computer over your network:

```
arp -a -i interfacename
```

This should work on any type of network, not just ad-hoc ones, but since it displays a cache value it only displays devices used fairly recently. It will display the IP addresses and their unique MAC addresses.

The TCP protocol is often used to transfer information; print jobs, for example. To see current and some very recent TCP connections you can use the `ss -t` command.